# Oracle won't start up for me now

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to login to Oracle, it prompts for a username and password,

but I'm getting this error

```
A-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

What should I do?.Thanks in advance

Comment: Check if the file system is mounted, if the pfile/spfile are in the right place, and if the content is correct. THIS IS URGENT IF IT IS PRODUCTION!! CALL ORACLE SUPPORT IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO

Comment: This isn't for production thank goodness, but I'm in a class and it's the end of the semester and this is housing all of my projects.

Comment: btw - I'm assuming it's a linux environment... let me know if it's windows. just notice it says in the error it's a linux :) follow my answer - I currently think the problem is with the login, and not with the DB..

Comment: Ok, I tried to fix it, using: set ORACLE_SID=noida, and then I restarted my linux system, then it works now. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: you're welcomed. make sure that if you have critical data in the DB - you back it up (Oracle DB is really really really!! reliable, but out of about 350 DB's I maintained/touched in 12 years, I had 3-5 DB's that I had to recover, and 1 that I lost... you don't want to lose critical information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it looks like either your environment is not set correctly
i.e. the ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID environment parameters are not set,

or the database has an issue.

Please check which of both, report it, so we could help you.

---

to check environment parameters

```
echo $ORACLE_HOME
echo $ORACLE_BASE
```

if any of them is not correct - change them to the right content - log in, and enjoy your DB.

If they're correct - check if Oracle process exists on the system

```
ps -ef | grep oracle
```